# Google sheet to pandas via shared link without credentials in python

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets

I wish to read a Google sheet to pandas. There are number of questions already answered on this topic, but all of the answers (using gspread, basically) require credentials.
Here I don't have (or want to have) the credentials, but have a shared link opened for view.

I can even download the buffer (as HTML) with `urllib.request`

So, given a shared link, or a buffer, but no credentials, how can I parse the Google sheet to a Python data structure?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the following endpoints.

#### `/export` endpoint:

- Direct endpoint url

  ```
  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SPREADSHEET_ID]/export?format=[FORMAT]&gid=(SHEET_ID)&range=(A1NOTATION)
  ```
- Export links returned by [`File:get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) in the drive api.

  ```
  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=[SPREADSHEET_ID]&exportFormat=[FORMAT]
  ```

#### Google vizualization endpoint:

- [Endpoint: `/gviz/tq`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#creating-a-chart-from-a-separate-spreadsheet)
- [Export parameters](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source#request-format): `?tqx=out:(FORMAT)`
- Sample url:

  ```
  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SPREADSHEET_ID]/gviz/tq?tq=(URL_ENCODED_QUERY)&sheet=(SHEETNAME)&range=(A1NOTATION)&tqx=out:(FORMAT)
  ```

where

- `SPREADSHEET_ID` is your spreadsheet id
- `FORMAT` is one of `CSV`,`PDF`(html,json supported only in gviz/tq endpoint;ods,xlsx,zip supported only in drive export endpoints)
- `SHEET_ID` is   sheet id as seen in the url `#gid=SHEET_ID`
- `SHEET_NAME` - Name of the sheet
- `A1NOTATION` - Range string like`A1:G5`

`()` suggests optional parameters and `[]` suggests required parameter.

Typically, you'd use `csv` as export format to get the file and use `pandas.readcsv()`, but `json`, `html` and `xlsx` are just as valid