# Text not read when using pd.read_csv() on a Google Sheet

Tags: pandas, csv, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-query-language

I am trying to read a Google Sheet using pandas pd.read_csv(), however when the columns contain cells with text and other cells with numeric values, the text is not read. My code is:

```
def build_sheet_url(doc_id, sheet_id):
    return r"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={}".format(doc_id, sheet_id)

sheet_url = build_sheet_url(doc_id, sheet_name)
df = pd.read_csv(sheet_url)



> df
   Column1  Column2
0       12       21
1       13       22
2       14       23
3       15       24
```

This is what the spreadsheet looks like:

[image: Spreadsheet screenshot]

I have tried using `dtype=str` and `dtype=object` but could not get the text to show in my dataframe. Specifying the encoding `encoding='utf-8'` did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because query doesn't support [mixed data types](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#overview):

> Data type. Supported data types are string, number, boolean, date, datetime and timeofday. All values of a column will have a data type that matches the column type, or a null value. These types are similar, but not identical, to the JavaScript types.

Use the `/export` end point(or drive-api endpoint instead):

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SPREADSHEET_ID]/export?format=[FORMAT]&gid=(SHEET_ID)&range=(A1NOTATION)
```

##### Related:

- [Google sheet to pandas via shared link without credentials in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63645457/google-sheet-to-pandas-via-shared-link-without-credentials-in-python/63649268#63649268)
- [Query is ignoring string (non numeric) value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68562518/query-is-ignoring-string-non-numeric-value)

Comment: When using `&gid=(SHEET_ID)` I get a `HTTPError: Bad Request` but replacing by `&sheet=(SHEET_ID)` solved the problem.

Thanks @TheMaster!

Comment: @NDen Consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of this post. Regarding (SHEET_ID), it needs to be a actual sheetId. You can see the url: `&gid=(SHEET_ID)`